# date function error in rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I am trying to add a date conditional to my controller index action:

```
    @events = Event.where("date" => Date.today.to_s).order("date").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
```

I am trying to make my view only show events that have a date value greater than or equal to today's date. For example if an event has a date value of 2013-05-13 it should not be shown because that event has already happened and only events with a date value of today's date or later should be shown.

The problem is, the index view isn't returning any events and I have created an with a date value of 2013-05-30 which means it should work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually going to return everything where the date equals today:

```
Event.where("date" => Date.today.to_s)
```

What you probably want instead is:

```
Event.where("date >= ?", Date.today)
```

ActiveRecord will interpolate the date into the `?`.  Also, you don't need to call `to_s` on it, ActiveRecord will the date for you.

Comment: This worked, another great learning experience! Thank you so much Adam

Comment: In the long run @coletrain's suggestion is a good idea as well if you're going to be using this query in more than one place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your model use a scope like so:

```
 scope :recent_event, lambda { where('date >= ?', Date.today ) }
```

Then in your controller write

```
@events = Event.recent_event.order("date").page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
```

Comment: You want to use a lambda, otherwise your recent events will depend on when the web server restarted instead of the current day.